# How can I handle a date such as '1990-03-27' in Glove model for creating embeddings?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to create embeddings for words in my document. What do I transform the above mentioned date into so that I can create embeddings in glove?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually it depends on semantics that you want a date to bear. It's very common to use a top level abstraction for dates - say, replacing them with a constant like 'anydate'. Still, i'm not sure that it's pretty good - you may want to have a richer date-related discourse.

Comment: Easiest way is to retrain the embeddings from scratch using the date as a token